# While adding data to a csv file from html form i get an error as illegal offset type on line 7

Tags: php, forms

```
<?php 
$data = array($_POST);
$csv_line = $data;
foreach ($data as $key) 
{
    array_push($csv_line, ''.$_GET[$key]); #This is the line where error occurs
}
$filename = 'students.csv';
$csv_line = implode(',', $csv_line);

if (file_exists($filename))
{
    $csv_line = $csv_line."\r\n";
}
$fcon = fopen($filename, 'a');
$fcontent = $csv_line;
fwrite($fcon, $csv_line);
fclose($fcon);
?>
```

I've written the code to accept form data from html and save it in a csv file using php

Comment: `$data = array($_POST);` vs `array_push($csv_line,''.$_GET[$key]);` ?

Comment: each field in the form i.e User id ,name,city  etc.

Comment: You're using the `$_POST` but try to get values from `$_GET`. Plus, `array($_POST)` will just wrap the `$_POST` in another array, so you'll have to access it like this : `$data[0]["YourInputName"]`

Comment: is it inappropriate

Comment: Barely any of that code appears to make much sense. By doing `$data = array($_POST);`, you have created an array that contains one single item under the key `0` now. Now you loop over that, so `$key` will _be_ the whole `$_POST` array now. So you are effectively trying to access `$_GET[$_POST]` here, which makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: if so can you guide me on the appropriate cide

Comment: It just makes no sense. That's like trying to get the content of the box A while searching in the box B

Comment: _“if so can you guide me on the appropriate c[o]de”_ - what you have shown makes so little sense, that this would basically mean for us to write the whole thing for you now - and that is not what this site is for. You should scratch what you have there, and start completely new. And this time, with a bit more logical thinking. And maybe you should work through a couple of beginner tutorials on working with arrays, and on working with files, as well.